# I've read that butterflies like sunflowers, do they also like sunchokes?

Tags: sunflowers, butterflies, sunchoke

With "adopting" a lot of monarchs last year (to see them grow), and starting a sunchoke patch, has anyone had any luck with their sunchoke patch attracting butterflies and caterpillars?

Comment: I believe different butterflys like different plants. Also have a look at http://monarchbutterflygarden.net/butterfly-plants/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sunchokes will tend to attract smaller butterflies, especially (in my experience), the European cabbage butterfly [(*Pieris rapae*)](http://Faunal%20Associations:%20The%20nectar%20and%20pollen%20of%20the%20flowers%20attract%20primarily%20bees,%20including%20bumblebees,%20cuckoo%20bees%20(Triepeolus%20spp.),%20digger%20bees%20(Melissodes%20spp.),%20leaf-cutting%20bees%20(Megachile%20spp.),%20Halictid%20bees,%20and%20Andrenid%20bees.%20Bees%20that%20are%20specialist%20pollinators%20(oligoleges)%20of%20sunflowers%20(Helianthus%20spp.)%20include%20a%20digger%20bee%20(Melissodes%20agilis),%20some%20Andrenid%20bees%20(Andrena%20accepta,%20Andrena%20aliciae,%20Andrena%20helianthi),%20a%20dagger%20bee%20(Pseudopanurgus%20rugosus),%20and%20a%20Halictid%20bee%20(Dufourea%20marginata%20marginata).%20Other%20floral%20visitors%20include%20Syrphid%20flies,%20bee%20flies%20(Bombyliidae),%20small%20to%20medium-sized%20butterflies,%20wasps,%20and%20beetles%20(Robertson,%201929,%20&%20others)). They might not be such an attraction to your monarch butterflies. Also see:

> Faunal Associations: The nectar and pollen of the flowers attract primarily bees, including bumblebees, cuckoo bees (Triepeolus spp.), digger bees (Melissodes spp.), leaf-cutting bees (Megachile spp.), Halictid bees, and Andrenid bees. Bees that are specialist pollinators (oligoleges) of sunflowers (Helianthus spp.) include a digger bee (Melissodes agilis), some Andrenid bees (Andrena accepta, Andrena aliciae, Andrena helianthi), a dagger bee (Pseudopanurgus rugosus), and a Halictid bee (Dufourea marginata marginata). Other floral visitors include Syrphid flies, bee flies (Bombyliidae), small to medium-sized butterflies, wasps, and beetles (Robertson, 1929, & others)

[(From here).](http://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/prairie/plantx/ja_sunflowerx.htm)